# Editing HTML in pages or content editor with software

Tags: visual-studio, css, html, wiki-pages, edition

I would like to do some advance customization in my wiki pages or content editors. For this, I use the HTML function, but the editor where I paste the code is not very user friendly.

Is there any way to edit these elements directly with software like Visual Studio or Dreamweaver? Or is it necessary to do everything in some extern software and then copy paste it to see how it looks like?

For the moment, I can use a content editor, linked to a txt file in some library in the space, which is the one I open with dreamweaver directly. Please feel free to suggest your systems. Thanks.

Comment: No answers? Please, I would appreciate your suggestions. Thanks.